# How to display a hidden image when a certain <option> is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to get a hidden image to show when a certain option from a dropdown input box is selected by the user and then the submit button is pressed, by using either Jquery or Javascript?

I am unsure how to obtain the option that the user selected?

This is the current code that i have to hide the images:

```
  <form>
    Please select which type of training program you would like: <select name="program">
      <option id="hiit"selected>HIIT High Intensity Training</option>
      <option id="cardio">Cardio Vascular</option>
      <option id="strength">Strength Training</option>
      <option id="toning">Toning</option>
  </select>
    Please select which area you are wanting to target: <select id="body">
      <option id="upper"selected>Upper</option>
      <option id="core">Core</option>
      <option id="lower">Lower</option>
      <option id="fb">Full body</option>
  </select> 
  <br><br><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="choice"> <br>
  </form>
<br>

 <!-- program choices -->
  <img src ="cardio.jpg" width ="350" height="200" id="cardio" class="pics">
   <img src ="hiit.jpg" width = "350" height="200" id="hiit" class="pics">
   <img src ="strength.jpg" width = "350" height="200" id="strength" class="pics">
   <img src ="toning.jpg" width = "350" height="200" id="toning" class="pics">


<script>
//hide pictures
$('.pics').css("display","none");

  </script>
```

Comment: You can't duplicate id's in a page...they are unique by definition

Comment: Read up on how `<select>` works and how `value` on `<option>` works

Answer (score 0):

First, I changed up some of your html. As charlietfl said, id's have to be unique. So, I made all the ids you gave to the options the values instead. I also changed your `input` of `type="button"` to a `button` with `type="submit"`.  I then went to the initial form tag and added an `onsubmit` attribute where the function `revealImage()` will be triggered.

The Jquery function is quite simple. It first hides all the images then takes the value selected from the first select option, and reveals the corresponding picture. My code specifically has your imgs' ids equal to the value plus "Id", but you can make your image ids completely different and use a switch-case statement to reveal the specific image with the value the user gave. Look  [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) to learn more.

Finally, I removed your initial javascript of hiding the images and just went to the css and set the images' displays to none.

I also added some css to the images as otherwise they wouldn't show up (as I don't have your image sources). Just delete that and add your sources.

Here are some links to help you understand some of the things I did in case you're confused:

[Why ID's must be unique.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

[Show / Hide](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp)

[Jquery val()](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
function revealImage(){
    $(".pics").hide();
    var value = $("#program").val();
    var picId = value + "Pic";
    $("#" + picId).show();

    return false;
}
```

```css
.pics:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color:red;
}
.pics:nth-of-type(2){
  background-color:blue;
}
.pics:nth-of-type(3){
  background-color:green;
}
.pics:nth-of-type(4){
  background-color:yellow;
}

.pics {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return revealImage();"> 
    Please select which type of training program you would like: 
    <select id="program">
        <option value="hiit">HIIT High Intensity Training</option>
        <option value="cardio">Cardio Vascular</option>
        <option value="strength">Strength Training</option>
        <option value="toning">Toning</option>
    </select>
    Please select which area you are wanting to target: 
    <select id="body">
        <option value="upper">Upper</option>
        <option value="core">Core</option>
        <option value="lower">Lower</option>
        <option value="fb">Full body</option>
    </select> 

    <br><br>
    <button type="submit"> Submit </button><br>

</form>
<br>

<!-- program choices -->
<img src="" width ="350" height="200" id="cardioPic" class="pics">
<img src="" width = "350" height="200" id="hiitPic" class="pics">
<img src="" width = "350" height="200" id="strengthPic" class="pics">
<img src="" width = "350" height="200" id="toningPic" class="pics">
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat similar to #Tuneer's answer. I left your markup alone as much as possible:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hide elements with CSS:

```
        <style>
            img.pics{
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
    Please select which type of training program you would like: 
    <select name="program" id="program">
      <option id="hiit" selected="selected">HIIT High Intensity Training</option>
      <option id="cardio">Cardio Vascular</option>
      <option id="strength">Strength Training</option>
      <option id="toning">Toning</option>
  </select>
    Please select which area you are wanting to target: 
    <select id="body">
      <option id="upper" selected="selected">Upper</option>
      <option id="core">Core</option>
      <option id="lower">Lower</option>
      <option id="fb">Full body</option>
  </select> 
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit">
```

Altered IDs here to be `data-` attributes. You cannot have the same id value on more than one element, but you are free to use the same value multiple times in `data-` attributes:

```
 <!-- program choices -->
  <img src ="cardio.jpg" width ="350" height="200" data-idval="cardio" class="pics" alt="cardio">
   <img src ="hiit.jpg" width = "350" height="200" data-idval="hiit" class="pics" alt="hiit">
   <img src ="strength.jpg" width = "350" height="200" data-idval="strength" class="pics" alt="strength">
   <img src ="toning.jpg" width = "350" height="200" data-idval="toning" class="pics" alt="toning">

        <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script>
```

Attach simple click handler to button. This code ensures that all images are initially hidden, and then finds the image with the `data-` attribute matching the id of the selected program. The selected image element then has CSS applied to display it.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('.pics').css("display","none");
    $('img[data-idval="'+$('#program > option:selected').attr('id')+'"]').css({'display':'block'});
});

  </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```